# Trying to get source code of a webpage in perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to get a html source of a webpage using the Perl  "get" function.  I have written the code 5 months back and it was working fine, but yesterday I made a small edit, but it failed to work after that, no matter how much  I tried.
Here is the code I tried.

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
my $link = 'www.google.com';
my $sou = get($link) or die "cannot retrieve code\n";
print $sou;
```

The code works fine , but its not able to retrieve the source, instead it displays

```
cannot retrieve code
```

Comment: ok thanks for that, but actually Im trying to get source of a local server page.  I get the page when I type  "gold/isos/preFCS5.4/LATESTGOOD/" in the my page  or http://gold.conf.com/isos/preFCS5.4/LATESTGOOD/"  I can see the page, but it doest work with perl "get". please help me in getting this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
my $link = 'http://www.google.com';
```

Comment: ok thanks for that, but actually Im trying to get source of a local server page.  I get the page when I type  "gold/isos/preFCS5.4/LATESTGOOD/" in the my page  or http://gold.conf.com/isos/preFCS5.4/LATESTGOOD/"  I can see the page, but it doest work with perl "get". please help me in getting this.

Comment: i mean I can see the content in my browser when I type gold/isos/preFCS5.4/LATESTGOOD/  or gold.conf.com/isos/preFCS5.4/LATESTGOOD/

Comment: Your browser will silently prepend 'http://' to the string that you type into the location bar. LWP::Simple doesn't do that, so you need to do it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit late,

I have been struggling with the same problem and I think I have figured why this occurs. I usually web-scrape websites with python and I have figured out that It is ideal to include some extra header info to the get requests.This fools the website into thinking the bot is a person and gives the bot access to the website and does not invoke a 400 bad request status code.

So I applied this thinking to my Perl script, which was similar to yours, and just added some extra header info. The result gave me the source code for the website with no strugle.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# This line specifies the LWP version and if not put in place the code will fail.
use LWP 5.64;
 
# This line defines the virtual browser.
$browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;


# This line defines the header infomation that will be given to the website (eg. google) incase the website invokes a 400 bad request status code.
@ns_headers = (
 'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/4.76 [en] (Win98; U)',
 'Accept' => 'image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/png, */*',
 'Accept-Charset' => 'iso-8859-1,*,utf-8',
 'Accept-Language' => 'en-US',
 );

# This line defines the url that the user agent will browse. 
$url = 'https://www.google.com/';
 
# This line is used to request data from the specified url above.
$response = $browser->get($url, @ns_headers)  or die "cannot retrieve code\n";;



# Decodes responce so the HTML source code is visable.
$HTML = $response->decoded_content;

print($HTML);
```

I have LWP::Useragent as this has the ability for you to add extra header infomation.

I hope this helped,

ME.

PS. Sorry if you already have the answer for this, just wanted to help.